# Creating sub-sub-domain on Amazon Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, amazon-route53

I'm trying to get my development environment as such:

```
dev.domain.com
dev.admin.domain.com

qa.domain.com
qa.admin.domain.com
```

I've created them just like I would create a sub-domain on the Route 53 page but it does not work. Anything I am missing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with S3...

Comment: I thought specifying my environment might be of importance.

Comment: You're creating a subdomain in Route53, not S3. S3's a file storage system.

Comment: Ok, changed the title!

Comment: I'm sure that this question has many duplicates, but the one linked to is NOT a duplicate of this actual question.

Answer (score 2):

It is always best to wait for a while when changing DNS configuration. It started working after a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something.*.example.com.

You can do *.example.com, which'll cover all of them, or change the order to something sensible like admin.dev.domain.com, *.dev.domain.com, admin.qa.domain.com, *.qa.domain.com, etc.

Comment: qa.*.domain.com was meant as qa.whatever.domain.com. I created a qa.admin.domain.com and I will not ping.

Comment: Again, you can't do something.*.domain.com. It won't work.

Comment: Again, I don't want to create something.*.domain.com. I want to create many sub domains and have qa, dev and staging subs for all of them.

Comment: So just do *.domain.com and have the server handle the rest. You can't do what you're trying to do solely with DNS.

Comment: It works now, I guess it just required propagation, funny that the sub domain worked instantly. I think the * is confusing you in my question. I will change the question.